# Why does require() return "an unfinished copy" of a module exports instead of a reference to it (circular dependency)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, commonjs

The usual behaviour of the `require()` function is to use caching. So if several modules request another one, all of them get references to the very same object represents exports of the required. However, according to the [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_cycles) there is an exception:

> When `main.js` loads `a.js`, then `a.js` in turn loads `b.js`. At that point,
> `b.js` tries to load `a.js`. In order to prevent an infinite loop, an
> **unfinished copy** of the `a.js` exports object is returned to the `b.js`
> module. `b.js` then finishes loading, and its exports object is provided
> to the `a.js` module.

Such behaviour tends to facilitate inconsistency due to what a module receives from `require()` depends on the precedence this module was given itself (`b.js` was required after `a.js`, so the former gets an unfinished copy of `a.js` export,  whereas the latter has a direct reference to `b.js` export).

What's the rationale for this approach? Why is it impossible to return a cached version of `a.js` export to `b.js` (which was created when `main.js` requested `a.js`)?

Comment: Actually, it doesn't return a copy. It just returns the initial value of `module.exports` - which  was an empty object when *a.js* started to evaluate. Depending on when exactly *a.js* does require itself, it will be unfinished, as you have not yet created all exports on it.

Comment: @Bergi This seems to be much closer to the truth than what the documentation says, but it's not necessarily the _initial_ value - it's just whatever `module.exports` happens to be at the time `require` is invoked. If the user decides to override `module.exports` fifty times, then they can obtain fifty-one different values from a `require` for he same module,  depending on when it was called (example 3 below demonstrates this).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sentence from the documentation is plain nonsense (at the time of writing - September 2023, it's still in there, and it's in **boldface**).

This is not what is actually happening.
It's not copying anything, it's just always returning the latest value of `module.exports`.

For example, if the `module.exports` is never overridden by the user, then the original automatically created object will be returned.

Consider the following example:

#### Example 1

```
// a.js

module.exports.message_1 = "this can be overridden from `b`, it's not a copy"
module.exports.message_2 = "this is what is meant by 'unfinished'"
console.log("start of 'a', msg-1:" + module.exports.message_1)
console.log("start of 'a', msg-2:" + module.exports.message_2)

const b = require("./b")

module.exports.message_2 = "now it's finished"

console.log("end of 'a', msg-1:" + module.exports.message_1)
console.log("end of 'a', msg-2:" + module.exports.message_2)
```

```
// b.js

const a = require("./a")

console.log("b, msg-1: " + a.message_1)
console.log("b, msg-2: " + a.message_2)
a.message_1 = "this is overridden from module 'b'"
```

```
// main.js

console.log("enter main module")
const a = require('./a')
console.log("exit main module")
```

When executed with

```
node main.js
```

it will print

```
enter main module
start of 'a', msg-1:this can be overridden from `b`, it's not a copy
start of 'a', msg-2:this is what is meant by 'unfinished'
b, msg-1: this can be overridden from `b`, it's not a copy
b, msg-2: this is what is meant by 'unfinished'
end of 'a', msg-1:this is overridden from module 'b'
end of 'a', msg-2:now it's finished
exit main module
```

As one can see from the line

```
end of 'a', msg-1:this is overridden from module 'b'
```

printed from module `a` after requiring `b`, the module `b` can mutate the original `module.exports` from `a` without any problems. It doesn't get an "unfinished copy", it gets the direct reference to the original.

---

#### Example 2

If the user overrides `module.exports`, then one of course should pay attention to the fact that modules that are circularly dependent on the changing `module.exports` will end up with outdated references:

```
// c.js
module.exports.d_as_seen_from_c = require('./d')
```

```
// d.js
module.exports.message = "this is the first object"
require('./c')
module.exports = {
  message: "this is the second object"
}
```

```
// main.js
const d = require('./d')
const c = require('./c')

console.log("Final state of 'd' = ", d)
console.log("'d' as seen from 'c': ", c.d_as_seen_from_c)
```

Here, if one runs `node main.js`, one will obtain:

```
Final state of 'd' =  { message: 'this is the second object' }
'd' as seen from 'c':  { message: 'this is the first object' }
```

That is, `c` will end up with the outdated reference to the "first" version of `module.exports` of `d`, which is later overridden by a "second" version in the subsequent steps of loading `d`.

But, again, these are plain references to the same objects, no "unfinished copies" are created anywhere.

---

#### Example 3

Note that the *"plain references"* mentioned in the previous paragraphs don't actually have to be references to objects, they can also be primitive values.

Consider this example, where `a`'s `module.exports` is changed two times, from the initial object, to a primitive value, then to a new object:

```
// a.js
module.exports.label = "this is the provisional automatically created object"
require('./b')
module.exports = "that's not even an object, it's just a plain string"
require('./c')
module.exports = {
  label: "this is the final object"
}
```

```
// b.js
module.exports.a_as_seen_from_b = require('./a')
```

```
// c.js
module.exports.a_as_seen_from_c = require('./a')
```

```
// main.js
const a = require('./a')
const b = require('./b')
const c = require('./c')

console.log("a = ", a)
console.log("a as seen from b = ", b.a_as_seen_from_b)
console.log("a as seen from c = ", c.a_as_seen_from_c)
```

The `require('./a')` will return three different values in three different positions, dependent on what the value of `module.exports` in `a` was at the time when the `require` was invoked:

```
a =  { label: 'this is the final object' }
a as seen from b =  { label: 'this is the provisional automatically created object' }
a as seen from c =  that's not even an object, it's just a plain string
```

---

#### Conclusion

Thus, the initialization seems to proceed in a fairly straightforward manner:

1. The first time a module `x` is requested by `require('x')`, it will create a blank object, assign it to `module.exports` in module scope, and then proceed with the execution of the code in module `x`.
2. If during the execution of the code in module `x` the `require('x')` is invoked again (e.g. from a circularly dependent module), it will simply return whatever is currently in `module.exports`.

Or, even more tersely:

> Is the requested module already there?
> Yes: return it. No: create it.

No "unfinished copies" anywhere, as far as I can tell.